# Updating contact email in user trigger in Salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, force.com, soql

I have a trigger on a user object that is triggered on user updating and updates the contact fields (user linked to this contact), such as first name, last name and email. First and last name are updated correctly, but email field is not updated. I think, this is due to the fact that changing a user's email to be confirmed through a link that comes in the letter. But when I confirm the change by email, contacts still not updated:(

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some shade field update on user when email change by workflow rule, and it will be execute trigger.